# Find part of a string and remove it from an array

Tags: php, arrays

i need to find which is the key containing the part of the value and doesn't show it

```
$arr = array(0 => "helbor_000", 1 => "ez_000", 2 => "xx_333");
    $find = "helb";
    $key = array_search($find, $arr);
    foreach($arr as $index => $value){
          if($index != $key){
              echo $value;
          }
    }
```

Comment: ... and? What's your question?

Comment: how it works...my code probably is wrong and i have no idea where the problem is @AmalMurali

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preg_grep()` can do it

```
$arr = array(0 => "helbor_000", 1 => "ez_000", 2 => "xx_333");
$find = "~^helb.*$~";
$ret = preg_grep($find, $arr, PREG_GREP_INVERT);
print_r($ret);
```

Comment: thank you.. it worked.. what if i needed the opposite of that show the match only??

Comment: @EddieD.: In that case, simply remove `PREG_GREP_INVERT`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array(0 => "helbor_000", 1 => "ez_000", 2 => "xx_333");
$find = "helb";
foreach($arr as $index => $value){
    if(strpos($value, $find) === false) {
        echo $value, PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $arr;
       ^
```

should be $key or $value;

Comment: sorry i wrote it wrong.. i gonna update