# How to retrieve those entries from an array that contain the prefix `TEST`?

Tags: php, arrays, string

```
$data[0] = "TESTaabsc";
$data[1] = "ffgaabsc";
$data[2] = "TESTffga";

for($i=0; $i<sizeof($data); $i++)
{
if (!is_null($data[$i][0]) && (???)) 
{
//...
}
}
```

How to retrieve those entries from `$data` that contain the prefix `TEST`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find part of a string and remove it from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361477/find-part-of-a-string-and-remove-it-from-an-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($data); $i++)
{
    if(strpos($data[$i], 'TEST') === 0)
    {
        // $data[$i] has the prefix
    }
}
```

Or to get the matches in a new array you can use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$result = array_filter($data, function($var){
    return strpos($var, 'TEST') === 0;
});

print_r($result); // $result is an array containing the matches only
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `array_filter()`

```
$results = array_filter($data, function ($value) {
    return 0 === strpos($value, 'TEST');
});
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

or if you're familiar with regular expressions, try `preg_grep()`

```
$results = preg_grep('/^TEST/', $data);
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php)

The difference is that `strpos()` is likely to be faster than `preg_grep()` because regular expressions can be expensive. It all depends on the data size you're searching.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions to the rescue!

```
$filtered = preg_grep ('/^TEST/', $data);
```

Comment: Seriously? A regular expression for such a simple string operation?

Comment: Yes, and why not? The code is a lot more compact this way, isn't it?

Comment: Regular expressions are costly. And I fail to see how your code should be more compact than `strpos($data, 'TEST') === 0`.

Comment: There's no point to analyse cost if he only needs to filter a handful of strings. Things like database queries take A LOT more time. Optimizations like this one should only be applied when there's a known bottleneck. As for being more compact: `preg_grep()` processes the whole array at once, while `strpos()` only tests one element, so should be put in a loop.

Answer (score -1):

You could do this:

```
if (!is_null($data[$i][0]) && strpos($data[$i], 'TEST')) {
//...
}
```

What this does is check which position data[$i] contains the string 'TEST'. If it isn't found it will return false.

Comment: Give a nice explanation for your answer, instead of pointing only the code